# Error: "undefined reference to ‘__udivsmodsi4" when switching compilers in Contiki 2.6

Tags: gcc, compilation, compiler-errors, msp430, contiki

I am switching from contiki 2.7 to contiki 2.6 but have found that the sky-shell-exec example does not build with msp430-gcc 4.5.3 in contiki 2.6.  To get around this while using contiki 2.6 I am trying to install msp430-gcc 4.6.3.

I have downloaded the deb package for 4.6.3 from http://helpdesk.jogjaprov.go.id/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-msp430/

and have used the following commands to try and install it:

```
sudo apt-get remove gcc*
sudo apt-get remove gcc-msp430
sudo dpkg --force-all -i ~/Downloads/gcc-msp430_4.6.3~mspgcc-20120406-3_i386.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
```

When I do a *msp430-gcc --version* it returns:

```
msp430-gcc (GCC) 4.6.3 20120301 (mspgcc LTS 20120406 unpatched)
```

So it seems that it has worked...

However, when I try to do a make sky-shell-exec.sky TARGET=sky in examples/sky-shell-exec/ I get two following error:

```
usr/lib/gcc/msp430/4.6.3/../../../../msp430/lib/mmpy-16/libc.a(vuprintf.o): In function `vuprintf':
/build/buildd/msp430-libc-20110612/src/./stdlib/vuprintf.c:387: undefined reference to `__udivmodsi4'
/build/buildd/msp430-libc-20110612/src/./stdlib/vuprintf.c:397: undefined reference to `__udivmodsi4'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sky-shell-exec.sky] Error 1
```

I thought at first thought that this might mean that my system has two different versions somehow tangled.  But, I haven't been able to confirm or deny this.
I have check my version output with that found at http://www.george-smart.co.uk/wiki/Installing_Contiki and everything is the same except that my output says "... --build=i686-linux-gnu ..." instead of "... --build=x86_64-linux-gnu ..."

My questions are:

1) What am I doing wrong?

2) How does one switch msp430-gcc compilers from 4.5.3 to 4.6.3 to work with contiki 2.6?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you paste the code in which error is coming?

Comment: Did you check this - http://sourceforge.net/p/mspgcc/mailman/mspgcc-users/thread/D45E6EE7-2771-41EC-9999-F773C6B22AA4@imag.fr/

Comment: The command that gives the error is the one I have above:  "make sky-shell-exec.sky TARGET=sky" in the examples/sky-shell-exec/ directory.

Comment: Yea I have seen that post.  That's why I posted the output of my version to show that it seems there is only one version currently installed.  But maybe there is another way to confirm/deny this other than doing "msp340-gcc --version"?  I have also checked under /opt/ and see only 4.6.3.